# Best time span (time difference) format for CSV

Tags: excel, csv, time, spreadsheet

This question is very analogous to [Best timestamp format for CSV/Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804118/best-timestamp-format-for-csv-excel):

I'm writing a CSV file. I need to write *time spans* (a.k.a. time differences) that are accurate at least to the second, and preferably to the millisecond. What's the best format for timestamps in a CSV file such that they can be parsed accurately and unambiguously by programs like Excel with minimal user intervention?

Preferably in a format that is still easily humanly parseable even if it spans several days, i.e. instead of `265:00:00` something where a human can spot that it is 11 days without doing calculations in his head.

I should add that I am generating the CSV outside of Excel, so this is not about getting data *out* of Excel, or formatting data *in* Excel, but how to format a plain CSV file so that both Excel and Humans can make sense of time span values.

Answer (score 1):

For any arbitrary number of days, the problem is not creating the format, its reading the **.csv** back into Excel once created.  For example if a cell contains:

```
134.45632176823
```

its value as days/time is:

134 days, 10 hours, 57 minutes, 6 seconds, 201 milliseconds

Even if you could format the cell to display:

134 10:57:06.201

and then saved the file as **.csv,**, upon re-opening the file, Excel would interpret the value as a string rather than a days/time *(a human would have no problem interpreting the format)*

**EDIT#1:**

if you enter 1.23456789 if a cell and format it as d hh:mm:ss.000 it will display as:

1 05:37:46.666

If you then save the file as **.csv** and open the **.csv** with NotePad, you will see the as-formatted text.  If, however you re-open the **.csv** with Excel, you will find a text cell rather than numerical cell formatted as days/time.

Excel does not have this problem with a cell containing a standard date like 1/25/2014

Comment: The problem with `134.45632176823` is that a human would not be able to make much sense of it. I'm looking for something that my application can generate that Excel will not interpret as just a string -- if that is even possible.

Comment: If the number of days is less than or  equal to 31, then you could use the **Custom Format** : d hh.mm.ss.000

Comment: And Excel detects this format in a CSV file? Note that this question is *not* about formatting inside Excel.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Suboptimal, then, but it might well be that there is no solution for the problem.

Comment: Well.....except for the problem of "human understanding", the easiest approach is to leave the value without format.....it can be stored and retrieved without error.

Comment: What do you mean by without format – I am generating the file myself; I need to write *something*.

Comment: I mean using a **NumberFormat** like "0.00000000000"

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Excel

```
"y/m/d h:mm:ss.000"
```

and it returned `07/1/10 10:14:02.016` for the difference between 1/1/2007 00:00:00 and 11/1/2014 10:14:02.016

Comment: So if I put a string of that format in a CSV file and open it with excel, it is detected as a time difference? I would have expected it to be parsed as a date...