# Problem with export date to csv file, how to export date to excel

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, export

I have problem with export of date to my .csv file.
I have this two strings:

```
string Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss");
string Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:HH:yyyy");
```

Time is working normal and I get to csv file right data, but Date is written to cell as "0,905324074074074".
I found the problem, when creating the csv I have pName[2] = Date+";";
There is ; for shift to next cell, but it does this weird thing, i do not know why.
Code for create csv:

```
        private void SaveFileMeasure(string fileNameWithPath, string textMer, bool deleteExist)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                if (!deleteExist)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(fileNameWithPath, textMer);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(fileNameWithPath, textMer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vytvoření souboru neproběhlo v pořádku.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Thank for help.

Comment: I ran the code you posted, yet I got the output `21:11:2020`

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804118/best-timestamp-format-for-csv-excel

Comment: Please add the code you are using to write CSV. Maybe the bug is there.

Comment: Thanks for the edition, but still there is no code for constructing CSV lines, especially those with expressions like  `pName[2] = Date+";";`. What I'm trying to say: we need a minimal working example to reproduce this behaviour on our machines.

Answer (score 2):

Your format of date is incorrect, Try `"dd:MM:yyyy"`

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy");
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhWL6v)

Comment: Hey @Dufino, Did my answer help you? or you have something else as an issue?

Comment: It is does not help..
Maybe there is problem with export to .csv file I am usiing File.WriteAllText for create .csv file

Comment: It would be great if you update your question and mention error which you are facing even after using proper date format